# Gitlab pipeline with Vault authentification

Tags: gitlab-ci

I'm using a `Gitlab 13.11.1 enterprise edition` with `free` subscription.

I'm trying (into my pipeline) to authenticate to a `Hashicorp Vault`.

To achieve that I need the `CI_JOB_JWT` predefined variable.

According to [that page](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) the variable is available since version 12.10 and all tiers (free)

But [that guide](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/authenticating-with-hashicorp-vault/) tells it is only for premium.

When I'm trying it seems the variable is empty (or not available).  I have a missing token error when trying the vault write ...

How can I be sure the `CI_JOB_JWT` is (or not) available with the free subscription ?

Comment: `How can I be sure` Asking random people on some forum unrelated to gitlab is definitely not the way to be sure - you can't trust those people (well, unless you can). Ask gitlab employes or inspect the source code of gitlab server or runner. This is also not a programming problem. Are you sure you want to ask "how can I be sure" question? Why not ask "how to connect to hashicorp vault from gitlab-ci/cd?" ?

Comment: I understand your point of view.  But perhaps someone knows a gitlab link where it is writen that the variable in only available for premium (or not).  For the `why not ask` the response is simple.  I know how to do.  Lot of guides are explaining it.  But none is telling something about the CI_JOB_JWT availability according to the subscription.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late but as I was testing a Vault config with a free tier "license" (on gitlab.com however, not with a dedicated instance), I can confirm the CI_JOB_JWT token is there and it works.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).